# SharePoint 2013 Online CQWP, using design manager can't filter on a managed metadata column

Tags: 2013, content-query-web-part, filter, metadata, design-manager

I reviewed a lot of articles and couldn't find anyone talking this issue.

My issue is when I use Design manager to create a CQWP snippet, I always get error message when try to filter against a Page field, which is a managed metadata column. The error message is, "Please specify one of the following [PageFieldValue: (field name)] or [PageQueryString: (query string parameter name)] or an integer value for setting up a dynamic date range for date fields."

And here is my scenario. I need to create a related article web part.

I plan to use CQWP on a page layout. The page layout is based on a custom content type inherited from "Article page". This custom content type has a metadata column called "My Fruit". This web part is suppose to return the articles have the same property value as the page it resides on.

In Design manager, I am able to select the Page library, the content type, under "additional filters:" section, I set "My Fruit" is equal to, there are a few options for that selection, one of them is "Custom Value or Query", I filled it in as, PageFieldValue:My Fruit. When click update button, I got the error message as described above.

I tried remove "My Fruit" and filter it by "Title", so it looks like this,

Title is equal to PageFieldValue:Title, that works.

So I know it works for system string column and I got the format right.

I also tried set "My Fruit" is equal to, "Please edit on server" option, then I select a single term, i.e. "Apple". This way it works too.

Thanks in advance for your time and help!